# Magento2 how to modify admin grid collection using ui component

Tags: admin, collection, grid, magento-2.2.5, data-provider

You guys would be knowing that usually, we are using core Magento DataProvider while creating admin grid using UI component.

Sometimes, we need to add some filter or modify the basic grid collection data which brings all records stored in the respective table by default. For this, we need to create custom DataProvider to return our modified collection.

Can someone please provide some details or good reference regarding how can we make such DataProvider in the custom module for admin grid page?

That would be really helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution for this. It's really good which I didn't believe that it can be such easier.

Here, is the solution which you need to put in your ui component grid listing xml file:

Inside the `<dataSource>` tag :

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="product_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
          </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Here, you need to add respective field name 'product_id' and put it's value as '*' by default. This will take product_id param value dynamically which you pass from the url.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

See this, hope it helps.

> https://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-1.html

Thanks,

Comment: Hello @John. The reference link you provided is making grid using block and layout files not using UI Component.

Comment: check this one. https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-a-grid-using-ui-component/

Comment: Hi, @John. I already checked the above link you posted. Actually, that link shows basic way to create admin grid using UI Component. It is using core magento Data Provider instead of the custom one.